# Using TFS, how can I determine when a method was added to a source file?

Tags: tfs

I have a source file, it's about 10 years old, with 100's of changes.  I was able to use a manual binary search to identify the point at which a particular method was added.

Is there a more efficient way to do this in TFS?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using visual studio, you can check the history of the source file or choose `annotate` from the right click menu  to see how each block of lines are changed by the author.